# Finding Duplicates in an array using a Set in C++

Tags: c++

I am currently practicing for coding interviews and am working on a function that takes in an array and the size of that array and prints out which numbers in it are duplicates. I have gotten this to work using the two for loop method but want an optimized solution using sets. Snippet of the code I have is below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

void FindDuplicate(int integers[], int n){
  set<int>setInt;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

    //if this num is not in the set then it is not a duplicate
    
    if(setInt.find(integers[i]) != setInt.end()){
      setInt.insert({integers[i]});
    }
    else
      cout << integers[i] << " is a duplicate";
  }
}

int main() {
  
int integers [] = {1,2,2,3,3};

int n = sizeof(integers)/sizeof(integers[0]);

FindDuplicate(integers, n);
}
```

Any helpful advice is appreciated, thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Using plain old sort would be faster than using `set`. both will take `O(n*log(n))` time, but `set` has lots of unnecessary pointers for this problem. Generally you should always use `array` or `vector` unless there's a clear benefit of another data structure.

Comment: I believe you meant to use `==` instead of `!=` here: `if(setInt.find(integers[i]) != setInt.end())` As written that condition is true if the number already exists in the set.

Comment: @MadScientist sorry about the lack of clarity, what i was asking was how to properly use a set to find duplicates in an array

Comment: If you really need to use a set (because of some (for us) unknown requirements or limitations) then use `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for the helpful pointer, that was what was causing my code to to come to the right outcome. I am having trouble understanding why it should've been a "==" over "!=" and if you could explain a bit I'd appreciate it

Comment: find returns an iterator to the item searched for or the end iterator if the item doesn't exist. `find(...) != end()` means the item was found, and `find(...) == end()` means it was not.

Answer (score 4):

I think your comparison is not needed, insert do it for you:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert

> Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or
> to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool value set to
> true if the insertion took place.

Just insert element and check what insert function returns (false on second element of pair in case of duplication) :)

Answer (score 0):

my solution proposal is :

- count the frequencies of each element (algo for frequencies are explained here [frequency](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-frequencies-of-array-elements/)
- display elements with frequency more than 1 (it is a duplicate)

In each operation, you do not use imbricated loops.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

void FindDuplicate(int integers[], int n)
{
    unordered_map<int, int> mp;

    // Traverse through array elements and
    // count frequencies
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mp[integers[i]]++;
    }

    cout << "The repeating elements are : " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (mp[integers[i]] > 1)
      {
          cout << integers[i] << endl;
          mp[integers[i]] = -1;
      }
    }
}

int main()
{

    int integers [] = {1,1,0,0,2,2,3,3,3,6,7,7,8};

    int n = sizeof(integers)/sizeof(integers[0]);

    FindDuplicate(integers, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my feedback:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

// dont' do this, in big projects it's not done (nameclash issues)
// using namespace std;

// pass vector by const reference you're not supposed to change the input
// the reference will prevent data from being copied.
// naming is important, do you want to find one duplicate or more...
// renamed to FindDuplicates because you want them all

void FindDuplicates(const std::vector<int>& input) 
{
    std::set<int> my_set;     
    // don't use index based for loops if you don't have to
    // range based for loops are more safe
    // const auto is more refactorable then const int
    for (const auto value : input)
    {
        //if (!my_set.contains(value)) C++ 20 syntax 
        if (my_set.find(value) == my_set.end())
        {
            my_set.insert(value);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Array has a duplicate value : " << value << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    // int integers[] = { 1,2,2,3,3 }; avoid "C" style arrays they're a **** to pass around safely
    // int n = sizeof(integers) / sizeof(integers[0]); std::vector (or std::array) have size() methods 

    std::vector input{ 1,2,2,3,3 };
    FindDuplicates(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a set.
To find the duplicates:

1. Sort array with numbers
2. Iterate over the array (start with second element) and copy elements where previous element equals
   current element into a new vector "duplicates"
3. (Optional) use unique on the "duplicates" if you like to know which number is a duplicate and do not care if it is 2, 3 or 4 times in the numbers array

Example Implementation:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void
printVector (std::vector<int> const &numbers)
{
  for (auto const &number : numbers)
    {
      std::cout << number << ' ';
    }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int
main ()
{
  auto numbers = std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 2, 42, 42, 42, 3, 3, 42, 42, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7 };
  std::sort (numbers.begin (), numbers.end ());
  auto duplicates = std::vector<int>{};
  std::for_each (numbers.begin () + 1, numbers.end (), [prevElement = numbers.begin (), &duplicates] (int currentElement) mutable {
    if (currentElement == *prevElement)
      {
        duplicates.push_back (currentElement);
      }
    prevElement++;
  });
  duplicates.erase (std::unique (duplicates.begin (), duplicates.end ()), duplicates.end ());
  printVector (duplicates);
}
```

edit:
If you have no problem with using more memory and more calculations but like it more expressive:

1. Sort numbers
2. Create a new array with unique numbers "uniqueNumbers"
3. Use "set_difference" to calculate (numbers-uniqueNumbers) which leads to an new array with all the duplicates
4. (Optional) use unique on the "duplicates" if you like to know which number is a duplicate and do not care if it is 2, 3 or 4 times in the numbers array
   Example Implementation:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void
printVector (std::vector<int> const &numbers)
{
  for (auto const &number : numbers)
    {
      std::cout << number << ' ';
    }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int
main ()
{
  auto numbers = std::vector<int>{ 2, 2, 42, 42, 42, 3, 3, 42, 42, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7 };
  std::sort (numbers.begin (), numbers.end ());
  auto uniqueNumbers = std::vector<int>{};
  std::unique_copy (numbers.begin (), numbers.end (), std::back_inserter (uniqueNumbers));
  auto duplicates = std::vector<int>{};
  std::set_difference (numbers.begin (), numbers.end (), uniqueNumbers.begin (), uniqueNumbers.end (), std::back_inserter (duplicates));
  std::cout << "duplicate elements: ";
  printVector (duplicates);
  std::cout << "unique duplicate elements: ";
  printVector ({ duplicates.begin (), std::unique (duplicates.begin (), duplicates.end ()) });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here's a quick solution use an array of size N (try a big number)
and whenever a number is added into the other array on the large array add 1 to the position like:
array_of_repeated[user_input]++;
so if the program asks how many times (for example) number 234 was repeated?
std::cout<<array_of_repeated[requested_number]<<std::endl;
so in this way you wont spend time looking for a number inside the other list

Comment: You should format your answer properly and add punctuation. As it stands here your answer is hard to read.

Comment: That might be WAAAy too big. What if the possible numbers are `0` to `2^62 - 1`? Radix sort would be a good option - but doesn't perform better than quicksort unless the array is really huge.